# HashCode Deduplication?

Tags: apex, duplicate-management, hashcode

**Background:**

Ever since I found out you can [Use Custom Types in Map Keys and Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm), I wondered if you can map data by the `hashCode` value. *I suspect it's a bad idea.*

I understand the basics of how hash tables work, and I know collision is possible, but I am not sure how to measure the probability. I found [this article](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/) which has a bunch of useful information and seems to confirm my hunch.

- Does `Apex` also have 2<sup>32</sup> possible values?

  - (looks to me like the same max int)
- Can the `hashCode` values for the same object really change?
- Would the proposed `sha1` alternative be computationally expensive in `Apex`?

**Scenario:**

I have a `Location` object (~2400 records) which I want to sync from an address field. Since this functionality involves creating child records, I want a way to quickly check if an address is already in the system. If it already exists, simply don't create the record. If they added a rule to duplicate management where you just drop records that already exist, I could just use that. So how viable is it to use `hashCode` for de-duplication purposes?

```
public class CompositeAddress
{
    final Id accountId;
    final String street, city, state, postal;
    public CompositeAddress
        (Id accountId, String street, String city, String state, String postal)
    {
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.postal = postal;
    }
    public Integer hashCode()
    {
        return xor(street.hashCode(), xor(city.hashCode(),
                xor(state.hashCode(), postal.hashCode())
        ));
    }
    Integer xor(Integer a, Integer b) { return a ^ b; }
}
```

**Alternatives:**

- Just query all siblings and use `CompositeAddress` as a map key.
- Construct a hash using the `sha1` algorithm.
- Concatenate values into a text key.

I think a collision probability of < 0.5% is tolerable, but I'm not sure if my data set fits within that bound. My bigger concern is, if the algorithm can actually hash the same object in different ways, I might create duplicate records by trusting the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - Does Apex also have 2<sup>32</sup> possible values?
>
>   - (looks to me like the same max int)

[Yes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex3_4.htm).

> - Can the hashCode values for the same object really change?

HashCode means different things in different contexts. Since I do play with them from time to time, I know that the implementations are pretty consistent, but not across data types. For example:

```
System.debug(System.hashCode(1));  // [Integer] 1
System.debug(System.hashCode(Decimal.valueOf(1))); // [Decimal] 31
System.debug(System.hashCode(Double.valueOf(1))); // [Double] 1072693248
System.debug(System.hashCode('A')); // [String] 65
System.debug(System.hashCode(new Account())); // [Account] 0
System.debug(System.hashCode(new Account(Name='A'))); // [Account(Name='A')] 2420458
```

While String.hashCode seems to be stable and consistent (note that 'A' is Unicode 65, which means the algorithm is based on some computation of the bits), it should *not* be relied on.

> Would the proposed sha1 alternative be computationally expensive in Apex?

You can use [Crypto.generateDigest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_generateDigest) to make your comparisons.

```
Integer hashCode = System.hashCode('hello world');
```

> 100,000 hashCode calls against 'hello world': 4.724 seconds

```
String sha1Code = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(
           Crypto.generateDigest('sha1', Blob.valueOf('hello world'));
```

> 100,000 generateDigest calls against 'hello world': 17.211 seconds

As you can see, in order to make a sha1 code that you can store in a text format (at minimum), you need about 4 times more CPU time for 100,000 records.

Note that since your proposed algorithm was calling hashCode four times, using sha1 would be marginally *faster* than using hashCode, assuming you simply concatenated the strings together:

```
String sha1Code = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(
    Crypto.generateDigest(
        'sha1',
        Blob.valueOf(street+'♥'+city+'♥'+state+'♥'+postal)));
```

Finally, all of this is still bit-dependent, so to really catch duplicates, you need to compare like case to like case:

```
String sha1Code = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(
    Crypto.generateDigest(
        'sha1',
        Blob.valueOf(
            (street+'♥'+city+'♥'+state+'♥'+postal).toLowerCase()
        )));
```

You can use a case-indexed field to make looking up duplicates easier. You'll still want to *verify* if they're duplicates by comparing each of the four fields, but you'll save about 99% of the work by building digest codes. Once you queried potential duplicates back into memory, you can then use hashCode/equals to verify those duplicates.

So, in conclusion... do not trust hashCode outside of the current transaction, make sure you take case sensitivity into account, and always double-check potential duplicate candidates to make sure they really are equal.

Edit: Also, you could use sha256, also supported, to get much longer values and reduce the chance of collision significantly.

Comment: I like the ♥ joined address haha.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I usually use ☺, ☻, ♥, ♦, ♣, etc to join strings, because those characters don't normally appear in addresses and other types of "normal" data. Doesn't matter what you use, of course, as long as it's consistent. I just like using ♥'s. Hopeless romantic?